# jQuery each() isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running a jQuery function that is supposed to modify the width of a video depending on its width.

I have a bunch of videos in my page and I want to adapt them to the video container somehow, which has a fixed width. So in the function I was talking about before I check if the video width is higher than the container's, so then the video width should be changed to 100%, instead of auto, which is the property that all the videos have originally.

Here is the function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('video').each(function() {
        if ($(this).css('width')>$('.player-container')[0].css('width'))
        {
            $(this).css('width', '100%');
        }
    }); 
});
```

How every video is placed:

```
<div class="player-container">
   <video class="player-video" width="auto" height="auto">
        <source src="video/mana-labios-compartidos.mp4">
        <source src="video/mana-labios-compartidos.webm">
   </video>
   // more stuff about the video...
</div>
```

The thing is that I am placing an alert inside each `.each()` and I only see one, it pops just for the first video of the page actually.

Comment: If you console.log($('video').length) what do you get?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?  Don't just use an `alert` but place an actual debugging breakpoint and observe the runtime values/behavior.

Comment: `$('.player-container')[0].css('width')` is wrong because `[0]` returns a DOM node. You can't call `css` on that.

Comment: @Jon Ok, thanks, that was not the problem anyway.

Comment: @dabadaba: Considering that it will result in an error and the error will cause JS to *stop executing after the first* element... perhaps it's relevant? It's not the whole story of course.

Comment: So it because the error inside the anonymous function...

Comment: Do you got each video different .player-container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a jQuery object as an array, and specifying an index will actually return the DOM element, and thus the jQuery functions aren't supported. If you want the first element in the matched set, use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Also, try using the [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function instead (since it returns an integer, rather than the string returned by `.css('width')`. This is particularly handy for comparrisons such as those you're running.

Your final code would be:

```
if ($(this).width() > $('.reproductor-container').width())
```

Comment: To expand: `.css('width')` returns a string while `.width()` returns a number. If you want to compare widths you need numbers. You can also `parseInt()` the return from `.css('width')` in order to compare.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson Thanks, I was in the process of expanding the answer when you commented.

Comment: In each `each()` iteration the alert reports that $(this).width() is 0, except for the first video when I reload the page sometimes, the rest not even reloading.

Comment: @dabadaba for video, you'd have better to use window onload handler instead of document ready. And btw, why not just set directly width:100%; in CSS for video. I guess i don't understand your logic there

Comment: @A.Wolff Because some videos are smaller than the container, setting the width to 100% would mean a loss of video quality. How would that be? $(window).load(function (){}); Like that? Because that does not work either.

Comment: @dabadaba OK, so you want the actual source width of the video file itself, rather than the browser's calculated width for the `<video>` element?

Comment: I want the actual size width of the video if it is smaller than the container, or set it to 100% (adapt it to the container) if it's bigger.

Comment: I had to do some different adjustments, but this answer helped me partially. Thanks.

Comment: @dabadaba You can also use `parseInt($(this).css('width'))` but that will likely return 0 as well since the video hasn't been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your selector is wrong

instead of using

```
$('.player-container')[0].css('width')
```

try to use

```
$('.player-container').eq(0).css('width')
```

for beeing safe that .css('width') is returning a number and not a string like "200px"

```
if (parseInt($(this).css('width')) > parseInt($('.player-container').eq(0).css('width'))){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.player-container')[0]
```

gets an element, so

```
$('.player-container')[0].css('width')
```

will give a TypeError. Try

```
$('.player-container').css('width')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

`.css()` is a method that should be used on a jQuery object, but you're using it on the DOM element inside the jQuery object. Also, it returns a string which would be useless in your case, so you need to use `.width()` instead, which returns an integer. If you need to target an element by index, use `.eq()`.

This is how you finished code should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('video').each(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > $('.player-container').eq(0).width()){
            $(this).css('width', '100%');
        }
    }); 
});
```

This might not be suitable for you, but I think the same effect can be achieved with CSS alone, by setting the `max-width` on every video element to `100%` as follows:

```
.player-container video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem causes because you don't go to the relative video container. Do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('video').each(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > $(this).parent().width())
        {
            $(this).css('width', '100%');
        }
    }); 
});
```